# How to add items to utility bar in managed lightning package (specifically FSC - Financial Services Cloud)?

Tags: lightning, managed-package, financialforce, utility-bar

When trying to add items to the utility bar in the Financial Services Cloud managed lightning package, I get the following message:

> You can't edit the utility bar. This app is from a managed package.

Unfortunately there is key functionality we would like to add. I've tried other non managed apps and it works perfectly. Is there a way around this problem when working with Financial Services Cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed package items are mostly only available for the publisher to modify (if you're curious, you can read more at [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)). Generally, publishers will include a default component that can be upgraded, but that means that subscribers are locked out from making changes. Instead, you can create a new utility bar, add the FSC components to it, and assign it to the profiles you'd like to use.