# Can I update the Lightning console utility bar "Phone" UI?

Tags: lightning, utility-bar

We are using Amazon Connect CCP and **I'm trying to update the highlighted section of the screenshot to change color and display the text of the user's status** (i.e. "Available", "Offline", etc).

[image]

I can do this in Classic console using `sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentButtonStyle` and `sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentButtonText`. Is there a Lightning equivalent to this? Or can someone confirm if this is not supported in Lightning console yet?

I have explored using the `<lightning:UtilityBarAPI>` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:utilityBarAPI/documentation). It works for custom utility bar items (great example [here](https://rajvakati.com/2018/03/08/lightningutilitybarapi-sample/)), but from experimenting it looks like the Phone utility item cannot be updated (out of the box Salesforce item).

Any and all information and direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you went in the right direction. The Phone utility item is not a standard salesforce utility item, it is likely that you are using a Managed Package App utility bar and its items which is why they are locked. The solution is to create your custom utility bar, add the items and open it to the desired profiles. Then the utility items will be open via the API. See similar answer here:

[How to add items to utility bar in managed lightning package (specifically FSC - Financial Services Cloud)?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214121/how-to-add-items-to-utility-bar-in-managed-lightning-package-specifically-fsc)

Answer (score 0):

Currently (till salesforce Spring'20) sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentButtonStyle is not supported. But sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentButtonText is working fine in lightning view.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon API in Lightning updates the "Phone" text with the agent status in API version 45.0 and above. This solved my use case and wanted to post here for anyone else who runs into this unique case.